# Tree view display details webpart

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a SharePoint List, I need to create tree view of List Items and if I click on the list item in the tree view I should get the details as shown in the pic.

How can I achieve it using WebPart?

[image]

Comment: do you need this tree view be Categorized by any column ?

Comment: Yup, It need to be categorized by employee name.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Webpart, You can use TreeViewControl and add bind your data Source to that TreeView Control. And on click Event of each item you can populate the details on the Right hand side. You can add Label Controls on the Right hand side of the WebPart and populate them on click of each item.

[Example for TreeView Control](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-TreeView-server-control-in-ASPNet-with-examples-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

Comment: Example for TreeView Control Link is not working

Comment: Sorry the link got wrong. Please check now.

Comment: Thanks for your honest reply.This is extracting data from sql server.In my case i need to extract data from SharePoint list.Can you guide me in achieving this.

Comment: Yes, in the GetData method please add your code to get data from Your SharePoint List.